# I need to change the cell color in excel with a timer

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a script that monitors the folders and putting the results in an excel file. Is there a method when a cell that has been changed after 30 minuts that it gets a green color gets? and if the cell has not been changed after 30 minutes it will get a red color?

I forgot to mention that I want to check multiple cells.

Here is a [picture](http://gyazo.com/4d216359f66a5e5d5bcd1ba6f139225a). everything under f

I hope this is clear since my English is not good. laatste import(last import) needs to be checked

My code:

```
'===== 
Const adVarChar = 200 
Const adDate = 7 
Const adBigInt = 20
'============================================================================== 
'Set objecten 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
set objPadImport = fso.getfolder("\\netko-sbs\data\imports\") 
Set SubfolderImport = objPadImport.SubFolders
ExcelBestand = "\\netko-sbs\data\imports\output.xlsx"
Set objFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\Vbscripttest\importV3\lokaties.txt",  ForReading)


'Waarden
Const ForReading = 1
Dim arrFileLines()
i = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
  arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
  i = i + 1
Loop
objFile.Close
'============================================================================== 
'WScript.Sleep 10000 'Sleeps for 10 seconds
'============================================================================== 
'create a custom disconnected recordset 
'with fields for filename and last modified date. 
'==============================================================================
'Record set maken 
'============================================================================== 
set rs = createobject("ador.recordset") 
rs.fields.append "foldername",adVarChar,255 
rs.fields.append "moddate",adDate   
rs.fields.append "naam",advarchar,255
rs.fields.append "tijd", advarchar,20
'==============================================================================
'Excel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE 'Foutmeldingen uitschakelen
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add() 'Bestand openen..
'objWorkbook.SaveAs(ExcelBestand)
objExcel.Visible = True  'toon excel
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "foldernaam" 'Header instellen
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Laatste import" 'Header instellen
objExcel.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Controle tijd" 'Header instellen

x = 2 'set de juiste rij in excel. 
'============================================================================== 
rs.open 
'===== 
'load it with file name, date, etc. (mapen controleren)
'==============================================================================
'==============================================================================             
For Each strLine in arrFileLines
     s = split( strline, "," ) 
     set folder = fso.getfolder( s(0) ) 
     'set test = (folder.datelastmodified - s(2))

     rs.addnew array("foldername","moddate", "naam", "tijd"), _ 
           array(folder.name,folder.datelastmodified, s(1), s(2)) ',test) 
     rs.update 

Next

s = "Sortering van Oud naar Nieuw:" & vbcrlf  _ 
  & "=============================" & vbcrlf 
if not (rs.bof and rs.eof) then 
  rs.sort = "moddate asc" 
  rs.movefirst 
  do until rs.eof 
    objExcel.Cells(x, 1).Value = _
        rs.Fields("naam").Value 
    objExcel.Cells(x, 2).Value = _
        rs.Fields("moddate").Value 
    objExcel.Cells(x, 3).Value = _
        rs.Fields("tijd").Value 
        x = x + 1
    rs.movenext 
  loop 
end if 


'Excel
Set objRange = objExcel.Range("A1") 'Selecteer actieve cell
objRange.Activate 'Activeer cell

Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
objRange.Autofit() 'Set grootte van kolom

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("B1") 'Selecteer actieve cell
objRange.Activate 'Activeer cell

Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
objRange.Autofit() 'Set grootte van kolom

Set objRange = objExcel.Range("C1") 'Selecteer actieve cell
objRange.Activate 'Activeer cell

Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
objRange.Autofit() 'Set grootte van kolom
'==============================================================================
VarType moddate = objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Laatste import"
if DateDiff("n",moddate,Date) < 30 then 
objExcel.Cells(y,y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
Else objExcel.Cells(1,1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 

end if
'==============================================================================
ObjWorkbook.SaveAs(ExcelBestand) 'Excel bestand opslaan
'objExcel.Quit 'Excel afsluiten als nodig is.
'==============================================================================
'==============================================================================

'objFile.WriteLine s 'Schrijf waarden naar Excel
Set rs = nothing 'Gooi RS leeg 
Set folder = nothing 'Object leegmaken
set fso = nothing 'Object leegmaken
set objPadImport = nothing
set objPadFrigo = nothing
set SubfolderFrigo = nothing 
set objExcel = nothing
'==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

getlastmodified time of cell store it in one of cell or in variable.

for example : 
if you store the time in one of cell then,

var lastmodifitime = objExcel.Cells(x,1).Value

'if cell value is modified in last 30 minutes then it set red, else if it not modified in last 30 minutes or more it set background Color green

if DateDiff("n",lastmodifitime,Date) < 30 then
    objExcel.Cells(y,y).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
Else
    objExcel.Cells(z,z).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
end if

' this link will help you to get last modified time : http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/track-changes-in-excel/

Comment: This code is very helpfull. I am using this right now and it works almost. The only problem is that it marks everything red or green. It doesnt matter if its bigger or smaller than the object. [This is the result in excel](http://gyazo.com/d851d2670a092c65443ae17afa324443). [And this is the code](http://gyazo.com/1d328c1ae0fca35e13064d82530df412).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Application.OnTime()` function to call an Excel subroutine after a certain interval. If you're just trying to monitor a single cell, you could use a single flag to specify whether the cell's value has changed. The `Worksheet_Change()` event could be used to update the flag.

For example, in a `Module`, add the following code:

```
' Create global flag to indicate if cell value has changed.
Public CellChanged As Boolean

' Call this routine to start the monitor.
Public Sub StartMonitor()
    CellChanged = False    ' Init
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "CheckIfChange"
End Sub

' This will be called by the monitor after 30 mins.
Public Sub CheckIfChange()
    If CellChanged Then Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
End Sub
```

Then, in your worksheet, just add a bit of code that updates the global flag if your target cell's value has changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 2 Then If Target.Column = 2 Then CellChanged = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks very helpfull but it's kinda complicated for me. I would like to know how to use this on my script. I'm new to this with no experience so it would be great if you can show me how. I will post the code into my question.

Comment: The code I've shown above is for Excel VBA. You could add it to a workbook and save it as a macro-enabled workbook or template. Then, using VBScript, open the workbook (or create a new workbook based on the template) and call the `StartMonitor` function when you're ready. I don't think you're going to be able to accomplish what you need using VBScript alone.